# Skip minification of certain folders with asset-pipeline

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline

I have a collection of javascript files in my assets folder that don't work correctly after the minification process has been applied to them. I'm therefore trying to exclude these specific files from the minification.

Tried the example in the documentation `grails.assets.excludes = ["tiny_mce/src/*.js"]` but that just excluded the files completely from the WAR file. Can this be solved by configurating asset-pipeline or do I have to move these files to web-app folder and try to access them from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the version `:asset-pipeline:2.8.0` or newer version you can use this options

```
grails.assets.minifyOptions.excludes = ["tiny_mce/src/*.js"]
```

and this will ignore the files you put in the pattern at the moment of the minify.
I hope this help you, it took me a while to find, because I was need it too.

source: https://github.com/bertramdev/grails-asset-pipeline/issues/284